# Md-select and Md-Scroll-Mask works unproperly

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a problem with [`md-select`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect) (Angular Material Design v1.0.0).

When pressing the select, it freezes and I can't press on anything - it stays open!

```
<md-input-container flex>
    <md-select ng-model="product.paymentCode" name="paymentCode"  md-on-open="loadPaymentCode()" placeholder="Payment Code"  required>
        <md-option ng-value="rPaymentCode" ng-selected="rPaymentCode.id==product.paymentCode.id" ng-repeat="rPaymentCode in paymentCodes">{{ rPaymentCode.code}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
    <div ng-messages="createProductForm.paymentCode.$error" ng-show="createProductForm.paymentCode.$touched">
        <div ng-message="required">choose payment code</div>
    </div>
    <tr-clear model-to-clear="product.paymentCode" ng-if="product.paymentCode"></tr-clear>
</md-input-container>
```

It worked before with this current version of angular material design. I've read all the CHANGELOG and nothing helped to figure it out.

Comment: Would it be possible to include the code that you're currently using to implement `md-select`?

Comment: Uploaded, thank you very much. This is not working in the whole website, it came out of nowhere, If I go back to version 0.11.4 in Angular Material Design it works.. But it worked with version 1.0.0 till now.. something happend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.. The problem was in the bower.json it was written like this 
'angular-material': '~1.0.0'

and the first time when I did 'bower update' it updated to '1.0.0-rc4' 
but the second time when I did 'bower update' it was 1.0.0 and it got wrong.

All the version 1.0.0-rc5 till 1.0.4 breaking md-select in my site.(I've checked each of them)
It still unclear how to solve the implemantaion of mdSelect in my site to fit the updated versions.

I suspect this what breaks;
"select no longer overflows window, resizes from small to big correctly"(version 1.0.0-rc5)

The Change Log
https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

I hope someone could help me understand how to fix it so I could upgrade to the newest version.

Thank you, Diana.